# Is there an API to map 'touch' input to a different monitors?

Tags: c++, windows-7

I am trying to achieve the same functionality as multidigimon.exe, that is mapping an input digitizer to a given monitor, I was wondering if there is an API I can access or if the multidigimon.exe supports any parameters I can call it with to automate the mapping process.

So far I have found that multidigimon.exe writes the following registry key

key:20-\\?\hid#&col06#1&4784345&d&0005#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}

value:\\?\DISPLAY#Default_Monitor#5&5e64b29&0&UID268435456#{e6f07b5f-ee97-4a90-b076-33f57bf4eaa7}

to
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Wisp\Pen\Digimon

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did not find an API; however, I think I know how to do it:

1. Find the monitor that you want to map the input to via EnumDisplayDevices, we are interestded in the DeviceID,
2. Find the correct instance of the input device
3. Write to the following registry key:

   ```
    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Wisp\Pen\Digimon
   ```

- key = [you input device path instances]
- value = [your monitor device path]

4. Restart wisptis.exe.

Comment: Can also be used if you system just doesn't recognize which screen has touch capabilities, and MultiDigiMon.exe fails to correct this... This was extremely helpful, been struggling with a touch screen for a week now because of the above ! Thanks a lot :D

Comment: How could I locate `wisptis.exe` and restart it?